# Why I can't normally show my data after binding in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

After I Binding the ObversableCollection to the DataGrid,The DataGrid Can't show my data.[image]

this picture show that the xx.xaml can use the Staff_Show.but this picture that the data can't be shown normaly.
[image]

my program are as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Staff_Show}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="姓名" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="税前金额" Binding="{Binding TB_Sum}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

and the .cs code :

```
    public ObservableCollection<Staff> Staff_Show = new ObservableCollection<Staff>();
    public TaxBefore_Sum(ObservableCollection<Staff> StaffAccept)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Staff_Show = StaffAccept;
        DataGrid1.DataContext = this.Staff_Show;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Datacontext = this
```

try this

**EDIT**

well you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

let's assume your class name is TaxBefore_Sum

```
public class TaxBefore_Sum : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new  PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Staff> staff_show = new ObservableCollection<Staff>();
    public ObservableCollection<Staff> Staff_Show
    {
     get { return staff_show;}
     set { staff_show = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Staff_Show"); }
    }
    public Taxbefore_Sum(ObservableCollection<Staff> StaffAccept)
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.DataContext = this;
         Staff_Show = StaffAccept;
    }

}
```

hope it works

Comment: I tried again,I found that works,thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = this.Staff_Show;
```

It should work. In addition, you should add

```
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

in the DataGrid Xaml tag.

Comment: It worked,but I can't understand why I have standered  'ItemsSource="{Binding Staff_Show}">',why I have to use DataGrid1.ItemsSource = this.Staff_Show; in the code,

Comment: If you want to use binding, please set the `Staff_Show` as property instead of field. WPF can only bind **Property** on the XAML. Then, you can follow Sakib Aman's solution to achieve your goal.